# Can not access the javax.servlet.error.* for error code 500 in JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces 5.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, exception, jsf-2.2

I am working on JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces 5.1, in my application for exception handling I have configured error code 500 in web.xml like below

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

and in 500.xhtml I am trying to access error code like below

```
<h:outputText  value="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}"></h:outputText>
```

at the time of testing I found that, I was redirected to a url like below
`https://localhost:8443/appname/500.xhtml`
which is wrong it should like `https://localhost:8443/appname/configerd_path`
and here I found that in `requestScope` I don't have `javax.servlet.error.*`
so I cannot display error code, error message and so on ...

I would like to ask here that, what is the best practice to handle this kind of error in JSF 2.2 and how can I access error code and error message ?

Comment: I don't follow: You have *500.xhtml* configured as the error page and you're saying the container is wrong to have redirected you to that page?

Comment: I want to say that, i dont have same request, response object, if it would be forward in place of redirect than i will have same request response object in place of new one .

Comment: Try `#{param['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}` instead. Also have your browser's developer's console open to confirm the parameter is being sent (and if not, what parameters are being sent)

Answer (score 2):

As I am using primefaces and it's provides a built-in [exception handler](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml) to take care of exceptions in ajax and non-ajax request easily.

with the following EL, I am able to catch exception at my 500.xhtml page.

```
<h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.exception}" ></h:outputText>    
<h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.type}"></h:outputText>                
<h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.message}" ></h:outputText>
```

I hope it helps others :-)